# Laravel 5.1 - get current route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, assets

I'm working on a function to get assets (.css, .js) automatically for each view. So it works fine for let's say, "http://mywebsite.com/displayitems", /home, /about etc.

But since I wrote the function using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, I came up with an issue when I had a route like `/displayitems/1` because of the "/1" in the route.

Back then in Laravel 4.x I had a great way to do it but sadly it doesn't work the same way in Laravel 5.4.

I've been searching through the internet for a good method to get the current route but no success. The thing is that I have to ignore any parameters in the request URL.

If anyone has a clue, or maybe am I doing it wrong and there's a completely different, better way to do it?

P.S My current function:

```
public static function getAllRouteAssets() {
    $route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($route == "/") {
        $tag = '<link href="' . asset("assets/css/pages/home.css") . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>';
    }
    else {
        // CSS
        $tag = '<link href="' . asset("assets/css/pages" . $route . ".css") . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>';
    }
    echo $tag;

    //TODO: Check if file exists, homepage condition, js...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try this:

```php
// Add the following (`use Illuminate\Http\Request`) statement at top your the class

public static function getAllRouteAssets(Request $request)
{
    // Get the current route
    $currentRoute = $request->route();
}
```

Update (Get the Request instance from IoC/Service container and call `route()` to get current route):

```
app('request')->route(); // Current route has been retrieved
```

If you want to pass the current route as a parameter to your `getAllRouteAssets` method then you have to change the `typehint` or pass the `Request` and call the `route` method from within the `getAllRouteAssets` method.

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. I'm using this function in my main layout file to load the assets in the header HTML tag. How can I get the current request in that .blade.php file (to pass as parameter to `\App\Helper\getAllRouteAssets();`?

Thanks again!

Comment: I am sorry to annoy you again with so many questions.
Once I have the request object, I want to get the staticPrefix of the request instance.
By var_dumping the instance, I realized that staticPrefix is private, it is a member of "compiled" which is protected.
How can I access it, since it's protected?

What I wanted to do, is let's say if I have a route like "website.com/displayitem/21333", this way I can get "/displayitem" and use this value to load assets specific for this page.

Thanks and sorry again.

Comment: P.S I know I can just edit the Route and CompiledRoute classes to make them public, but is it the right thing to do? @The Alpha

Comment: Sorry again, but fun fact - I tried to create a method as "getStaticPrefix", to publicly return the private value of "staticPrefix", but surprisingly it already exists! I'm happy to find this alone./

So to sum it up there's Route::getCompiled and CompiledRoute::getStaticPrefix which are already public.

Thanks a lot for your contribution and help!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but there is a method that gives you the entire query path:

`$request->getPathInfo();`

However, note that this will not work if you are looking to fetch the query string as well. (FYI, Laravel 5 does not support query strings by default)

You can individually fetch the GET variables from the query strings by:

`$request->input('id');`

Example:

`http://laravel.com/api/users/?id=123` would return `/api/users` using `getPathInfo()` and `123` using `$request->input('id');`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel 5.5.20. I had also need to get part of route without get parameters. Routes are defined  without question mark(?) in web.php, as for example:

```
 Route::get('board/{param_1}/{param_2}', 'BoardController@index');
```

In that case I did not see direct method in Route class to get part without url parameters.
Here is how I got static part (/board):

`...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
..
$staticPrefix = Route::getCurrentRequest()->route()->getCompiled()->getStaticPrefix();
...`