# Composer returning mysterious error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

Unfortunately, I do not know exactly what I did that caused this error to begin showing up whenever I run

```
composer update
```

from the command line.  I believe it happened after adding laracasts/integrated to my composer.json, but have a hard time believing that's the issue.  I did try removing laracasts/integrated and the problem remained.  Here's the exact error I get:

```
$ composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled

  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: REQUEST_URI

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--] [<packages>]...
```

After googling around, it appeared that perhaps deleting the composer.lock file and running

```
 composer install
```

might fix the problem, but that did not work for me.  I found a myriad of similar questions, but none that fit the exact error I was getting, so I was hoping someone with a lot of familiarity with these types of errors can help me debug it.

From what I can tell,

```
 php artisan clear-compiled
```

is causing this error, but again, I'm really unfamiliar with how to go about debugging this type of problem.

Thanks.

Comment: backup your project, then remove the vendor directory, throw a `composer update` once again. if it didn't work, perhaps moving your code to a fresh install laravel might help.

Comment: I have my project under version control in Git/GitHub so that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Try removing bootstrap/cache/compiled.php manually

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually don't see a file named compiled.php anywhere in my project.  That folder holds a .gitignore file and a services.json file?

Comment: @Tezla I tried cloning my project into a new folder.  When I run composer update, it gives the same error and doesn't generate a vendor folder.  Running composer install generates a vendor folder with the same error message as above when it's finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artisan boots a command line equivalent of the HTTP version of the app. Based on this error, you likely have a service provider (or some other bootable class) attempting to access the $_SERVER array, which is obviously not going to have a REQUEST_URI when run through command line.

Check your providers. If that doesn't light up the answer, search/grep for REQUEST_URI to find out which class is trying to use it.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts - I searched through my vendors folder for REQUEST_URI and didn't see anything that struck me as out of place.  Can you elaborate on how I can continue to search for where this undefined index might be originating from?

Comment: Did you only search your vendors folder? Have you written any middleware or service providers, or edited any of the packaged base Laravel classes? The /app folder is a good place to start.

Comment: I do have some middleware and service providers.  It seems like this problem started when I was adding some unit testing - in fact, it might have been when I tried pulling in laracasts/integrated from the command line (using cygwin)

Comment: Ah, I believe you are correct @Trip - I am using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in my service provider.  Do you have a suggestion as to what I can use instead?  The code works - so it's really frustrating that composer doesn't like it.

Comment: It's not composer that doesn't like it. Laravel's composer.json file tells composer to execute that artisan command. You could remove it from the "post-update-cmd" section, but then you'd be missing an important part of how Laravel works. You can probably use a "safe" getter for the URI to accomplish the same thing. Your answer will be similar to the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500988/laravel-5-1-get-current-route

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar error. (see below)

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
[ErrorException]
Undefined index: HTTP_HOST

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

I did grep the whole source and finally got the cause of the error.

I need to use the safer method than the method of PHP.

- source

  /app/Http/routes.php
- diff

  (before) $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

  (after) Request::server('HTTP_HOST')